# Why some questions are marked as community.

Tags: support, community-user

I found some of my questions marked as community ? I request you to kindly tell me what it is all about.

**EDIT :**

this is the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/is-this-class-of-functions-nonempty-nontrivial).

**EDIT:** This question is about why some questions have "Community" listed where usually one finds the last user to have modified a post in the thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would help if you link to the one that is so marked.

I see two interpretations to this question:

1. Your question is marked as "Community Wiki". That happens either because you've edited it too many times and triggered the automatic wikification (See [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/why-my-questions-were-turned-into-community-wiki) also), or because your question is a "soft" or a "big-list" question so that a moderator decided that it should be community wiki (as the question does not have a single correct answer).
2. You saw one of your questions appear on the front page after being bumped by the "Community" user. This happens to questions for which the questioner hasn't accepted an answer, and none of the existing answers have sufficiently many votes. This is the StackExchange platform periodically bringing unsolved questions back to the front page to get more exposure, and hopefully resolution.

Until you give more information, I have no idea which of the two (or perhaps a third option) you actually mean.

Comment: this is the question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/is-this-class-of-functions-nonempty-nontrivial

Comment: @Rajesh: Dear Rajesh, in your case it is probably because you hadn't accepted an answer to the question.

Comment: @Akhil : ok. thank you

Answer (score 7):

If you go to the ["User page" for Community](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (say, by clicking on the name), you will see in its description:

*Hi, I'm not really a person.*

*I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!*

*I do things like*

- *Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention*
- *Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them*
- *Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted*

So your question got "randomly poke[d]" because it is "unanswered" (i.e., has no accepted answer and no upvoted answers).

Comment: On StackExchange, "unanswered" means "has no upvoted answer". http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: @Rahul: To be more precise: no upvoted answers **and** no accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for the correction.